# sqlite3: count number of instances in column A for every unique instance in column B

Tags: python, sqlite

Say I have a sqlite table set up as such:

```
    ColumnA | ColumnB
   ---------|----------
       A    |    One
       B    |    One
       C    |    Two
       D    |    Three
       E    |    Two
       F    |    Three
       G    |    Three
```

Is there a query that would find the number of instances in Column A that have the same instance in Column B? Or would using a script to pull from rows (python sqlite3) be better?

for instance,

```
query("One") = 2
query("Two") = 2
query("Three") = 3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved by sqlite3 itself.

```
$ sqlite3 mydb.db
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /home/ziya/mydb.db                                        
sqlite> create table two_column( col_a char(5), col_b varchar(20) );
sqlite> insert into two_column values('A', 'One');
sqlite> insert into two_column values('B', 'One');
sqlite> insert into two_column values('C', 'Two');
sqlite> insert into two_column values('D', 'Three');
sqlite> insert into two_column values('E', 'Two');
sqlite> insert into two_column values('F', 'Three');
sqlite> insert into two_column values('G', 'Three');
sqlite> select * from two_column;
A|One
B|One
C|Two
D|Three
E|Two
F|Three
G|Three
sqlite> select count(*) from two_column where col_b = 'One';
2
sqlite> select count(*) from two_column where col_b = 'Two';
2
sqlite> select count(*) from two_column where col_b = 'Three';
3
```

If you are ok with python,

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> c = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
>>> cur = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(col_b) FROM two_column WHERE col_b = '{}' ".format('A'))
>>> [r for r in cur]
[(0,)]
```

You can easily make a function using above statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all counts at once, you can use grouping:

```sql
SELECT ColumnB, count(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ColumnB;
```